# How to use a cell content as a search criterion in an Excel table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have an Excel table, named *myTable*, the contents of which are shown below:

```
Partners    2-Jan   3-Feb   25-Mar  27-Mar
O2          20       23       26      0
Vodafone    1        23       25      29
Vectone     0         0       50      60
Orange      25       12       34      15
```

I have two more cells that contain the search criteria for

1. The Partners
2. The Dates

For example, cell A1 contains '3-Feb', and cell A2 contains 'Vectone'.

**I would like to use these 2 cells to make a selection from *myTable*.**
For example, using '3-Feb' and 'Vectone' would return 0 from *myTable*.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=INDEX(MyTable,MATCH(A2,rLabels,0),MATCH(A1,cLabels,0))
```

[INDEX](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/index_function.php)
[MATCH](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx)
[named range](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/excel2007/excel2007s7p6.html)

Comment: Thank you for the attempt. However, I left out mentioning a detail in my question: myTable would increase in size, so if we choose to name the column and row labels, we would have to do it each time the table expands.
To deal with this issue, I have adopted your answer to use the label and headers of my table. I will add my answer in a while.

Comment: If I understand correctly: When I assign names to the column and row labels, it may be OK for the present form of myTable. But in future, there would be more dates, and partners, so myTable would expand, and the named range would not be updated with it automatically.
But many thanks for your answer.

Comment: I am afraid I do not know how much large would be sufficient, so I have slightly tweaked your answer into a desirable solution in my answer :)

Comment: that is fine. I posted my answer before I realised that the max no. of rows and columns could be used (I am somewhat new to Excel).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to pnuts, whose answer I have adopted after slightly modifying it.

There were 2 problems faced in using cell contents as search criteria for myTable:

1. myTable would surely expand in future, with more dates and partners. If we renamed the column and row labels for myTable, and then added another partner and some dates, we would have to assign the names for these new partners and dates manually.
2. If I used the cell content of A1 directly, it resulted in an error. This is because the value in A1, 3-Feb, would be a date of a different format (2/3/2014) than that found in myTable (d-mmm). Hence, `Match` was not successful in this case. I have made use of `Text` function to convert the value in A1 to text in the required format, which resulted in a correct match.

The following is my answer adopted from @pnuts response.

```
=INDEX(myTable,MATCH(A2,myTable[Partners],0),MATCH(TEXT(A1,"d-mmm"),myTable[#Headers],0))
```

Here, myTable[Partners] refers to the column containing partner names, while myTable[#Headers] refers to the row containing dates.
The `Text` function converts cell A1 to text, allowing `Match` to function.

The following was my initial attempt, but for fear of slowing down Excel in future, when there would be lots of more partners and dates, I do not prefer it.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,myTable,MATCH(TEXT(A1,"d-mmm"),myTable[#Headers],0),FALSE)
```